# Find Similar Integers Between Two Numbers

Tags: java

There are two number variables. I want to confirm and print similar integers between these two numbers. Eg. Int num1 = 6229; int num2 = 2394. I want the program to print the shared integers of '2' and '9' and return 'true' for confirmation.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(hasSharedDigit(6229, 2394));
    }

    public static boolean hasSharedDigit(int firstNumber, int secondNumber) {

        int firstDigit;
        int secondDigit;

        while ((firstNumber > 0) && (firstNumber < 10000)) {
            firstDigit = firstNumber % 10;
            firstNumber /= 10;
            while ((secondNumber > 0) && (secondNumber < 10000)) {
                secondDigit = secondNumber % 10;
                secondNumber /= 10;
                if (!(firstDigit == secondDigit)) {
                    continue;
                }
                System.out.println(secondDigit);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You didn't say *how* it's not working, but that `return true` where it is can't be right. You have to set a boolean variable declared as false outside the outermost `while` loop, set it to `true` when you find a match and then return it at the end instead of that `return false`.

Comment: First, the term you are looking for is "digit" (a single character used in numbers, like "9" or "3"). An integer is what `int` contains - the whole number, like -668. Second, you should explain what the problem is: where does it fail, what it should have done instead, and if there are any error messages.

Comment: Also, why are you checking whether `firstNumber` and `secondNumber` are greater than 10000 *in the loops' conditions*? Since they can't grow inside your loop, just check them at the beginning of the method.

Answer (score 0):

The [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) (Don't Repeat Yourself) guides you to move repeated code to a reusable helper method, so you should create a method that extracts the digits of a number into a `Set`, allowing you to easily use [set intersection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_(set_theory)) to find the digits they have in common.

For this, a [`BitSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html) is the most appropriate "Set", so you could write the helper method like this:

```
private static BitSet digitsOf(int number) {
    BitSet digits = new BitSet(10);
    do {
        digits.set(number % 10);
    } while ((number /= 10) != 0);
    return digits;
}
```

Now it's very easy to find shard digits of two numbers:

```
public static boolean hasSharedDigit(int firstNumber, int secondNumber) {
    BitSet digits = digitsOf(firstNumber);
    digits.and(digitsOf(secondNumber));
    System.out.println(digits);
    return ! digits.isEmpty();
}
```

*Test*

```
System.out.println(hasSharedDigit(6229, 2394));
System.out.println(hasSharedDigit(0, 123));
System.out.println(hasSharedDigit(0, 404));
```

*Output*

```
{2, 9}
true
{}
false
{0}
true
```